# Update angular-devkit and got fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

in my Angular 8 +.net core 2.2 I've upgraded from Angular 8.2.1 to 8.2.7
after that I see in console windows that messages:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
.......................
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting CopyPlugin

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting angular-compiler

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      <s> [webpack.Progress] 100%

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 451 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 287 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 624 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.38 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.49 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-09-24T05:37:30.303Z - Hash: 688e97dd7591eb779072 - Time: 19723ms

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:2073, open your browser on http://localhost:2073/ **

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      i ∩╜ówdm∩╜ú: Compiled successfully.
```

seems the application is compiled and working and I found that angular-devkit is the probleme,if I revert to previous version all works fine
:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.5",
```

revert to

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.802.1",
```

is there any fix for using the latest version?

Comment: Seeing this issue as well since I jumped from Angular 7 to 8, still occurring on Angular 9.0.6. Builds fine but just annoying seeing these messages. 


Creating a new Angular 8 project through the template that uses dotnet core 3.1 seems to not have these messages, so perhaps updating dotnet core is the only solution. The template uses 
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.14" to start but I had to upgrade to "0.803.25" to fix caniuse lite outdated errors.

Comment: now I'm on .net core 3.1,Angular 9.0.7,  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7", but the same problem...

Comment: I see the issue on 9.1.0 as well but it only appeared after using ng update and the CLI changed a lot of files and added a lot of extra packages. I dont think it is the @angular-devkit/build-angular that is the only issue. If I had the time, I'd go through everything changed by the ng update, but just cant right now.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem like your when using

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3"
```

I always see fail log if the build is not success. After angular cli compile success everything will be fine

Comment: Is there an official bug report or something relating to this version?